# All form values not posted in Angular2 Form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

In my angular2 application, I have a google login oauth login page in which the user signs up with google, and is redirected to a profile page.On successful login, I redirect the user using the

```
navigateByUrl("/profile");
```

method. I am also setting a model, which gives the email of the user to the profile page through DI.
The problem I am having is all the contents of the profile page are not being posted in the method.Only the userName and userEmail values are posted.
Here's the code.

Profile.component.html

```
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addProfile(f.value, $event)">
        <div class="field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" [(ngModel)]="profileData.UserName" name="UserName" ngModel disabled><i class="icon-Name"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" [(ngModel)]="profileData.UserEmail" name="UserEmail" ngModel disabled><i class="icon-Email"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" #grades data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Enter Grade" [(ngModel)]="profileData.Grades" ngModel name="Grades" ><i class="icon-Class"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrapper">
            <!--<input type="text" #subjects data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Enter Subjects"  [(ngModel)]="profileData.Subjects" ngModel name="Subjects"><i class="icon-Subject" ></i>-->
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="primary-btn" >Save Profile</button>
    </form>
```

Profile.compontent.ts

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProfileData } from './profile.data';
import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Component, Input, Output, }     from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, NgForm, FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators   } from "@angular/forms";

declare var jQuery: any;
@Component({
selector: 'profile',
templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile.component.html',
providers: [ProfileService]
})

export class ProfileComponent implements AfterViewInit {
constructor(public profileData: ProfileData, public profileService:     ProfileService) {
    }

@ViewChild('grades') grades: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('subjects') subjects: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery(this.grades.nativeElement).tagsinput();
    jQuery(this.subjects.nativeElement).tagsinput();
}

addProfile(profile: any, event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();   // because of https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9936
    this.profileService.postUserProfile(profile);
}



}
```

The addProfile method either gets the username and email or grades only. 
Here's my DataModel.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileData {

   public UserName: string;
   public UserEmail: string;
   public Subjects: string[];
   public Grades: string[];
}
```

Comment: `all the contents of the profile page are not being posted in the method.` What do you mean? Which exactly content is not posted?

Comment: Only the userName and userEmail values are posted. Updated the question.Thanks

Comment: jquery plugin `tagsinput` breaks down your angular form. You can implement `ControlValueAccessor` to do it working with forms

Comment: Can you please give an example or link, sorry I am new to angular2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement ControlValueAccessor for `tagsinput` plugin:

```
export const TAGS_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => TagsInputValueAccessor),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[tagsinput]',
  providers: [TAGS_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class TagsInputValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_: any) => { };
  onTouched = () => { };

  $elem: any;

  constructor(private _elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.$elem = jQuery(this._elRef.nativeElement);
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.$elem.val(value).tagsinput('removeAll');
    this.$elem.tagsinput('add', value);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.$elem.on('change', (x: any) => this.onChange(x.target.value)).tagsinput()
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GezuafegWxZJuFxKMjHr?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify add (submit) to your form

```
 <form #f="ngForm" (submit)="addProfile($event)">
         .....
```